# NetBeanse IDE reports 'No suitable compilers were found on your system'

Tags: windows-7, netbeans, ide

I've installed `Netbeanse 6.9.1 for C/C++` . While opening the `IDE` its popping up a message like this

> No suitable compilers were found on your system. The IDE needs a suitable set of compilers and other build tools in order to work correctly.

From where do I download the C Compiler(Any LINKS). And how to make the IDE working. Please help me to do this

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: @MrShunz, tag seems to indicate Win7.

Comment: @Xenorose right... din't see that

Answer (score 1):

[This support page](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/60/cpp-setup-instructions.html) from NetBeans's site might give you the answers you need.

Comment: +1 also, here is the the page for the updated (6.9) version http://netbeans.org/community/releases/69/cpp-setup-instructions.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the [Cygwin setup](http://www.cygwin.com/setup.exe) and run it
2. On the Select Packages page you select the packages to download. Click the + next to      Devel to expand the development tools category. You may want to resize the window so you can see more of it at one time.
3. Select each package you want to download by clicking the Skip label next to it. At a minimum, select gcc-core: C compiler, gcc-g++: C++ compiler, gdb: The GNU Debugger, and make: the GNU version of the 'make' utility.

   Now add the Compiler directory to your path:

   - Open the Control Panel (`Start > Settings > Control Panel`) and
     double-click the System program.
   - Select the Advanced tab and click Environment Variables.
   - In the System Variables panel of the Environment Variables dialog, select the Path variable and click Edit.
   - Add the path to the cygwin-directory\bin directory to the Path variable, and click OK. By default, cygwin-directory is `C:\cygwin`.
     -Directory names must be separated with a semicolon.
   - Click OK in the Environment Variables dialog and the System Properties dialog.